# Programatically need to update the strongauthentication number for MFA from users contact info using mobile number in azure ADB2C

Tags: azure, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-graph-api, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I am migrating our existing website users to ADB2C via Graph API, and I want to enable MFA for the users.

[image]

So I am trying to update a Azure ADB2C user's mobile number to strongauthentication phone number for MFA so that when a user login, he would be sent the verification code and asked to verify the code for the given mobile number.

I have tried looking around for updating the user's authentication number and have seen that microsoft has provided an API to do so, but its in beta version, so was looking for alternative.

Please suggest on solutions

Comment: Are you looking for an automation solution or manual solution? The only automated solution will be the Graph API Beta API.

Comment: I am looking for a manual solution( basically programatically if I can do something)  rather than manually updating the details directly in azure portal